# Where can I find my .csv file after running my python code on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've just managed to run my python code on ubuntu, all seems to be going well. My python script writes out a .csv file every hour and I can't seem to find the .csv file.

Having the .csv file is important as I need to do research on the data. I am also using Filezilla, I would have thought the .csv would have run into there.

```
import csv
import time

collectionTime= datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
mylist= [d['Spaces'] for d in data] 
mylist.append(collectionTime) 
print(mylist) 
with open("CarparkData.csv","a",newline="") as f: 
    writer = csv.writer(f) 
    writer.writerow(mylist)
```

Comment: Could you include a copy of your code that is writing out to csv? Also, including the directory structure of your project will help

Comment: collectionTime= datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    mylist= [d['Spaces'] for d in data]
    mylist.append(collectionTime)
    print(mylist)

    with open("CarparkData.csv","a",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)    
        writer.writerow(mylist)

Answer (score 2):

**In short**, your code is outputting to wherever the file you're opening is in this line:

```
with open("CarparkData.csv","a",newline="") as f:
```

You can change this filename to the location of wherever you'd like the file to be read/written from/to. For example, `data/CarparkData.csv` if you had a folder named `data/` within your application dedicated to holding data files.

As written in your code, `writer.writerow` will write the lines to both python's in-memory object of the file (instantiated with `open("filename.csv"...)`, and the file itself (in this case, `CarparkData.csv`).

The way your code is structured, it won't be creating a new .csv every hour because it is using a static filename. If a file with this name did not exist at time of opening, it will create one, and if it did, it will continue to append new lines to the existing file.